# How to display all categories in Magento not top level category?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I tried this [link](http://niravkadiya.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/add-category-accordion-in-leftright-sidebar-in-magento/) and displaying all the categories in home page but it is displaying only the top level categories. I want to display all the categories.

```
<div class=”block block-verticalmenu”>
<div class=”block-title”>
<strong><span><?php echo $this->__(‘Categories’) ?></span></strong>
</div><!–End block block-cart–>
<div class=”block-content”>
<ul id=”ma-accordion” class=”accordion”>
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
<?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
<?php endforeach ?> </ul>
</div><!–End Of vertical-nav–>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topLeftLinks’) ?>
</div><!–End Of vertical-nav-container box base-mini–>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the function call

```
echo $this->drawItem($_category)
```

by

```
echo $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($_category)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```